EMF induced across ends of a moving rod
When a conducting rod moves with a velocity V perpendicular to a magnetic field with field intensity = B Tesla, an EMF is induced across the rod. If this rod is connected with metallic wires and the circuit is completed, current starts flowing in this circuit due to induced EMF in rod. Now, EMF is given by (V×B).L, where L is the vector representing the length of the rod. In the derivation of this formula, electrons inside the rod are assumed to be in equilibrium, giving E=V×B, where E= electric field. V in this case is the instantaneous velocity. Current is flowing through the circuit, which means electrons in the rod are also moving(that is, they're not in equilibrium). But the above mentioned formula for EMF still holds. How is this so?
